# How can qatar afford 220 billion dollar world cup?

Tags: gdp, development-economics

Qatar's gdp is just 146 billion dollar . But the cost to organize world cup 2022 is projected to be 220 billion dollars. It's just impossible to imagine for me. I don't think qatar gets imf bailout or other loans for such irrational extravaganza. How is qatar funding it then?

Comment: I own a flat that costs more than my yearly salary too. I think it is pretty clear how I could buy it? Did you mean to ask *why* they would host such an expensive world cup?

Comment: Why would Qatar need an IMF bailout? Qatar's Debt to GDP is comparatively low and has a [budget surplus](https://www.reuters.com/world/middle-east/higher-energy-prices-lift-qatar-budget-surplus-finance-ministry-2021-11-08/) at the moment. I second @Giskard. While government revenue is a fraction of GDP it seems to be about 36% of GDP in Qatar according to [Wikipedia](https://www.reuters.com/world/middle-east/higher-energy-prices-lift-qatar-budget-surplus-finance-ministry-2021-11-08/). The 220b are not spent in a year, and I wish my flat would be as cheap as this (compared to my income).

Comment: If it is a smart investment is a different story, but likely opinion based. In general, it is a lot of infrastructure investment as well, not just air-conditioned stadiums.